# Make .htm to hide

Tags: .htaccess

Need to make the site http://www.example.com/testimonials.htm
to http://www.example.com/testimonials using .htaccess.

Please help

Comment: FYI, this is a horrible question. This kind of question **should not migrated anywhere**. Doing so is like visiting your friend and dumping a turd on his doormat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.
  RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1.htm [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I am getting Internal Server Error

Comment: Sorry by misspelling, the code has been fixed

Comment: Thanks 
But the images are not loading . It showing "The requested URL /images/ess.jpg.htm was not found on this server."

Comment: Also in my site there is http://www.acfnfranchised.com/index.php it also showing the same error.

Comment: replaced RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.htm by RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.

Comment: I got my site working in this link http://www.acfnfranchised.com/testimonials but not working in http://www.acfnfranchised.com/testimonials/  please help

Comment: Need the site to work as testimonials and testimonials/ please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.htm$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I got my site working in this link acfnfranchised.com/testimonials but not working in acfnfranchised.com/testimonials please help

Comment: I edited my code, try it

Comment: Not working showing internal error

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.
  RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1.htm [L,QSA]
</IfModule> This code working fine but it has the issue testimonials/ not wrkng